# Angular 4 Dynamic Routing JSON

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-routing, angular4-router

I'm planning to load the routes dynamically via `JSON`. With the below piece of code on `ngOnInit`

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.getRoutes().subscribe((result) => {
      result.forEach((route) => {
        console.log('this.routes 1 ==>' + JSON.stringify(this.validationRoutes));
         this.validationRoutes.push({ path: route.path, loadChildren: route.loadChildren });
      });
      console.log('this.routes 2==>' + JSON.stringify(this.validationRoutes));
       this.router.resetConfig(this.validationRoutes);
    });
```

The getRoutes method reads from the JSON file,

```
    [
   {
        "path": "dmchannelmaster",
        "loadChildren": "../../martial-status/martialstatus.module#MartialStatusModule"
    }
]
```

but getting the error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

This has been done by referring to this StackOverflow,
[angular 2 lazy loading - routes from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982936/angular-2-lazy-loading-routes-from-server)

I'm trying to achieve similar to what has mentioned here,
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4234

But registering as part of the code (Hard Coding) works fine.